# Autocompleteextender in Ajax has a position issue in IE8

Tags: c#, html, ajax

I am working on AutocompleteExtender using ajaxControlToolkit. I have it working great in all the browsers except for IE8. IE7 works good too. The list that i see when i start typing in the textbox is not shown under the textbox. Instead you see the list somewhere else. I started to change values using firebug and realized "position:absolute" has to do something. So i changed it to fixed and it worked fine. But to change the position to fixed in the code, i don't know where that part of the code exits. Can someone help me so i have the list showed right under the Textbox.

This is in c# 2.0 using VS 2005.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the autocomeplete extender for ACT, and I have since moved to the JQuery option. The functionality is very similar, but it is much more customizable when it comes to styling and cross browser support. Take a look at it here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/